# Let the mvc-mini-profiler ignore Glimpse requests

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler, glimpse

I'm using mvc-mini-profiler along with Glimpse. The problem is glimse is flooding the profiler output with glimpse requests. Is there any way to ignore all request made by glimpse ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var ignored = MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths.ToList();
    ignored.Add("Glimpse.axd");
    MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths = ignored.ToArray();
}
```

Solution Posted here: 
[Mini MVC profiler: appears to be displaying profile times for every static resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648249/c-mini-mvc-profiler-appears-to-be-displaying-profile-times-for-every-static-res)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Glimpse will make Ajax requests if you have the Remote tab selected or when ever an Ajax request is made by your site.

This is done because when we detect that a request is made we proactively get the Glimpse data. We could probably switch this in a future release to be more lazy and only fetch the data on request.

Note, even though this will help, Glimpse will still be calling back to the server in the same way that Mini Profile does. Hence, both frameworks could probably try and ignore each other for ajax requests.

Hope this helps.