# Getting a profile report for images and js files

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using mvc3, and mvc mini profile is displaying multiple popup boxes for a single page request because it is profiling for images and js files.

Have you guys experienced this also?  What did you do?

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing those timings cause they are going through the managed pipeline. This also happens to mean that your page is a bit slower cause you have static content that is served dynamically.

See also, for details on how to disable it from being profiled: [Mini MVC profiler: appears to be displaying profile times for every static resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648249/c-mini-mvc-profiler-appears-to-be-displaying-profile-times-for-every-static-res)