# And still, what is the magic of ASP.NET MVC Content folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvc-mini-profiler

I've just moved my resource files (javascript, css, images) from `Content` folder to custom `Assets` folder. And I've noticed a strange behavior - these files are not longer cached by browser and [MvcMiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) shows separate request for each resource located in `Assets` folder:

[image: Before moving to Assets folder and after]

I know that `Content` folder isn't required by ASP.NET MVC convention, but why this happens? Is `Content` treated somehow especially by anyone (e.g. ASP.NET, IISExpress, etc.)? And how to force caching for other folders that contain static resources?

**EDIT:** Oh, it appears to be not an ASP.NET MVC odd behavior, but just the standard behavior of MvcMiniProfiler. Currently I'm checking that...

**EDIT:** Yea, there is no problem with ASP.NET MVC, it's just a [default configuration](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/MiniProfiler.Settings.cs#185) of MvcMiniProfiler to ignore only these paths: `"/mini-profiler-", "/content/", "/scripts/", "/favicon.ico"`. And these defaults can be easily extended:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths = MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths
    .Concat(new [] { "/assets/" })
    .ToArray();
```

Sometimes it's a good idea to read documentation before using something ;)

Comment: Similar question - [C# Mini MVC profiler: appears to be displaying profile times for every static resource!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648249/c-sharp-mini-mvc-profiler-appears-to-be-displaying-profile-times-for-every-stat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're indicating in your update, this appears to be a feature of MvcMiniProfiler:

```
/// <summary>
/// When <see cref="MiniProfiler.Start"/> is called, if the current request url contains any items in this property,
/// no profiler will be instantiated and no results will be displayed.
/// Default value is { "/mini-profiler-", "/content/", "/scripts/", "/favicon.ico" }.
/// </summary>
[DefaultValue(new string[] { "/mini-profiler-", "/content/", "/scripts/", "/favicon.ico" })]
public static string[] IgnoredPaths { get; set; }
```

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/MiniProfiler.Settings.cs#180).

Presumably, the images were never cached when you were serving them through Cassini, because Cassini is terrible at that (passing png files as application/octet-stream, for instance), but the issue was manually hidden from your view by MvcMiniProfiler.

Comment: Thanks, we were right :)! I've found the answer in the same file, but was wondering if this feature is documented somewhere, and haven't found any documentation or blog post, just the source code.

Answer (score 5):

This is a strange behavior. However, put the following code inside your web.config file which is under the root of your app:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

This code appends the necessary response headers in order for browser caching to work. You can tweak the time of course. For further info please refer : http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache